# Do we have to make more [cuts] or just keep [cutting]

Tags: discussion, tags

Both of those tags are in use:

[cuts](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cuts) and [cutting](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cutting)

I figure that they should fight to the death. Between the two which one is more logical to keep? Or is there a reason to keep both?

My vote is for keeping [cutting](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cutting) and I think we decided that pattern when we talked about stains and staining.

Answer (score 3):

That works for me.  It does follow with what was decided earlier.

Comment: I agree. Cutting follows our convention better.

Answer (score 0):

Since I got 2/3 mods agreeing on this one I have made tags changes on the following questions:

- [Turning a railroad tie into a bench, how to make a cut?](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/1987/turning-a-railroad-tie-into-a-bench-how-to-make-a-cut)
- [How do I cut thick wood with a jigsaw?](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/1793/how-do-i-cut-thick-wood-with-a-jigsaw)
- [Do wood cuts matter for wands?](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/1741/do-wood-cuts-matter-for-wands)
- [Should I do many shallow quick cuts or a single deep slow one with my router?](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/1215/should-i-do-many-shallow-quick-cuts-or-a-single-deep-slow-one-with-my-router)
- [How to make a long shallow cut on a narrow piece of wood with a circular saw](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/235/how-to-make-a-long-shallow-cut-on-a-narrow-piece-of-wood-with-a-circular-saw)

[cuts](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cuts) should be removed now I would think?